# Get file system free space in /proc

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, filesystems, proc

I wanna know if exist some file in /proc that shows the file system free space like the Ubuntu's command:
    df -h

```
root@localhost:~$ df -h
S. files                               SIZE   USE   FREE  %USE MNT IN
udev                                   1,9G  4,0K   1,9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                                  384M  1,2M   383M   1% /run
/dev/sda3                               95G   58G    33G  65% /
none                                   4,0K     0   4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                                   5,0M     0   5,0M   0% /run/lock
none                                   1,9G  1,2M   1,9G   1% /run/shm
none                                   100M   84K   100M   1% /run/user
```

I need the FREE column.

In /proc/partitions I can see the total space by file system, but i need the free one.

Anyone knows?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That information is usually provided by `statfs()` syscall, so no `/proc` entry.

Comment: bash cannot do that syscall without external utils(everything says `/usr/bin/$cmd: Input/output error`) - that's why I googled the same question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, `/proc` contains information about *processes*, not *filesystems*.  As mentioned, you're looking to parse the data from a `statfs()` system call.  `df` is the canonical shell utility for this; is there a reason you don't want to use it?

If you're not interested in parsing so many columns of data, you can use:

```
$ df -h --output=target,avail
```

Answer (score 3):

For systems that provide it, you can use the `stat` command on the filesystem.

For example

```
stat -f -c %a /var    # Find the number of free blocks on /var
stat -f -c %S /var    # Determine the block size
```

You need to multiply one by the other to get the number of bytes free, and then divide by the appropriate number of thousands to scale the result. Here's one way to get the result in MB for filesystem `/var`:

```
MBfree=$(( $(stat -f -c '%a * %S / 1024 / 1024' /var ) ))
echo "$MBfree"
```

Answer (score 1):

Programatically can be fetched with below sysfs functions

```
#include <sys/statvfs.h>

function: 
int statvfs(const char *path, struct statvfs *buf);

structure definition
struct statvfs {
               unsigned long  f_bsize;    /* file system block size */
               unsigned long  f_frsize;   /* fragment size */
               fsblkcnt_t     f_blocks;   /* size of fs in f_frsize units */
               fsblkcnt_t     f_bfree;    /* # free blocks */
               fsblkcnt_t     f_bavail;   /* # free blocks for unprivileged users */
               fsfilcnt_t     f_files;    /* # inodes */
               fsfilcnt_t     f_ffree;    /* # free inodes */
               fsfilcnt_t     f_favail;   /* # free inodes for unprivileged users */
               unsigned long  f_fsid;     /* file system ID */
               unsigned long  f_flag;     /* mount flags */
               unsigned long  f_namemax;  /* maximum filename length */

           };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Below command

```
df -Ph |awk 'NR >1{gsub("%","",$0);print }'| awk '{if($(NF-1)>60){print "Disk space issue exsists on partition "$NF" Used percentage is "$(NF-1)"% Used space is "$(NF-3) " out of total space "$(NF-4)}else{print "No disk space issue exsists on partition "$NF" Used percentage is "$(NF-1)"%"}}'
```